# List the content in the root directory [C programming]

Tags: c, file, ubuntu, system

I am looking for a way to extract the data from the 'Root Directory'.

This is using a FAT 12 floppy image. This is with Ubuntu Version 14.04.2.

I would like to be able to read the root entries found in the root sector (from what I understand this is sector 19 - 32), I would then like to be able to display the content stored in the entries (file names, directory names). This needs to be for system level programming.

```
traverse(){
    unsinged char buf[1000];
    int fd = open("CDBOOT1.IMG", O_RDONLY);
    lseek(fd, 19 * 512, SEEK_SET);
    read(fd, buf, 512);
}
```

I would like some information on how I can parse out the information in the buf array to get the information I desire. This is for a homework assignment, so I am not looking for a concrete answer, but maybe some resources on how to do this.

Update:
From advice, I used some of the other code (already written by someone else) so that it would print the HEX data of the sector I am trying to get the root data from (I can post the code for that if it is necessary). With the HEX table, I am still unsure how to interpret the data in order to get the file information, directory information, date created, etc.

Comment: In addition to the two very fine answers see if you can dig up a copy of the "Undocumented PC" as it has a lot of really god information in it about these sorts of things.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some parsing of FAT in the past. It can be tricky if you're not used to it.

One thing I'd strongly recommend is doing a hex dump of what you read in C and, save it in in a file and then bring it up in a good hex editor so you can verify that your algorithms are right and things are laid out as you expect.  That everything cross-checks which what you get from the spec.

Here is a spec:

http://www.maverick-os.dk/FileSystemFormats/FAT12_FileSystem.html

Comment: Great Reference you gave him.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good reference, I will read this over as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are really looking for two things here.  The FAT contains data the represents clusters and fragments of clusters.  But you also want to read the DET ( Directory Entry Table ) to get names and things like that.

So what you **REALLY** need to do is start here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table

and read up on how these things are designed.  This is neither simple or trivial code, even with an image file.  The image file may even have things embedded in it for the software that reads and writes it.